# How to tokenize my dataset in R using the tidytext library?

Tags: r, text, text-mining, tidytext

I have been trying to follow Text Mining with R by Julia Silge, however, I cannot tokenize my dataset with the unnest_tokens function.

Here are the packages I have loaded:

```
# Load
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(corpus)
library(corpustools)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(tokenizers)
library(stringr)
```

Here is the dataset I tried to use which is online, so the results should be reproducible:

```
bible <- readLines('http://bereanbible.com/bsb.txt')
```

And here is where everything falls apart.

Input:

```
 bible <- bible %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Output:

`Error in tbl[[input]] : subscript out of bounds`

From what I have read about this error, in Rstudio, the issue is that the dataset needs to be a matrix, so I tried transforming the dataset into a matrix table and I received the same error message.

Input:

```
 bible <- readLines('http://bereanbible.com/bsb.txt')


bible <- as.matrix(bible, nrow = 31105, ncol = 2 )
      
bible <- bible %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Output:

```
Error in tbl[[input]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any recommendations for what next steps I could take or maybe some good Text mining sources I could use as I continue to dive into this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `unnest_tokens()` expects a data frame not a character vector or matrix - try `tibble::enframe(bible) %>% unnest_tokens(word, value)`.

Comment: This works to get the following format:   name word     
   <int> <chr>    
 1     1 genesis  
 2     1 1        
 3     1 1        
 4     1 in       
 5     1 the      
 6     1 beginning
 7     1 god      
 8     1 created  
 9     1 the      
10     1 heavens

Comment: I didn't download the file so didn't test the code.  Just alerting you that the error was because the input format was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `readLines()`creates a vector, not a dataframe, as expected by `unnest_tokens()`, so you need to convert it. It is also helpful to separate the verse to it's own column:

```r
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)

bible_orig <- readLines('http://bereanbible.com/bsb.txt')

# Get rid of the copyright etc.
bible_orig <- bible_orig[4:length(bible_orig)]

# Convert to df
bible <- enframe(bible_orig)

# Separate verse from text
bible <- bible %>% 
 separate(value, into = c("verse", "text"), sep = "\t")

tidy_bible <- bible %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)

tidy_bible
#> # A tibble: 730,130 x 3
#>     name verse       word     
#>    <int> <chr>       <chr>    
#>  1     1 Genesis 1:1 in       
#>  2     1 Genesis 1:1 the      
#>  3     1 Genesis 1:1 beginning
#>  4     1 Genesis 1:1 god      
#>  5     1 Genesis 1:1 created  
#>  6     1 Genesis 1:1 the      
#>  7     1 Genesis 1:1 heavens  
#>  8     1 Genesis 1:1 and      
#>  9     1 Genesis 1:1 the      
#> 10     1 Genesis 1:1 earth    
#> # … with 730,120 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That was it! This format was the format I was trying to get it into, thank you!